# WordPress font does not works on Mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, custom-font

I have added custom font on my [website](https://flash-games.online/), it works on desktop, also if i open browser as mobile fonts works,but when i open it on mobile device ot tablet, font does not work.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: LTblackL;
    src:url(https://flash-games.online/wp-content/themes/vemlo/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT GEO 85 Heavy_1.eot);
    src:url(https://flash-games.online/wp-content/themes/vemlo/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT GEO 85 Heavy_1.ttf),
    url(https://flash-games.online/wp-content/themes/vemlo/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT GEO 85 Heavy_1.woff)format("woff"), 
    url(https://flash-games.online/wp-content/themes/vemlo/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT GEO 85 Heavy_1.woff2)format("woff2"), 
    url(https://flash-games.online/wp-content/themes/vemlo/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT GEO 85 Heavy_1.svg#filename)format("svg"),
    url(https://flash-games.online/wp-content/themes/vemlo/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT GEO 85 Heavy_1.otf)format("opentype");
}
```

this is how i do. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your font file urls in **quotes**, as they contain **whitespace.**

Check the **network tab in dev tools**: the fonts are **not loaded.**
Probably, you see a locally installed copy on your desktop device.

Change your `@font-face` like so

```
@font-face {
    font-family: LTblackL;
    src:url('https://flash-games.online/wp-content/themes/vemlo/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT GEO 85 Heavy_1.woff2')format("woff2"),
        url('https://flash-games.online/wp-content/themes/vemlo/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT GEO 85 Heavy_1.woff')format("woff"),
        url('https://flash-games.online/wp-content/themes/vemlo/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT GEO 85 Heavy_1.ttf') format("truetype");
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Besides, you can safely remove `.eot` and `.svg`.
.eot was only supported by Internet Explorers, .svg is no longer supported by Firefox or Chromium.

I also recommend to specify the `font-weight` otherwise different fonts might not be mapped correctly to elements that are bold by default (e.g `<strong>`, `<h1>`etc.)

You should also change the order of URLS starting with the most compact modern format (.woff2). If a browser can't use it, it skips to the next format (e.g. woff)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `@import` function.

```css
/* Import the font with the source url */

@import url("fonts.com/font/example");

/* Set the font for the website body */

body {
  font-family: "example";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all browsers support all fonts. It may be this font is not supported by the browser you're testing on.

You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet for tips on testing whether or not your fonts are loading.